# Powershell Move-Item works but shows error "the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process'

Tags: powershell, file

I have a powershell script that is running the following script that moves my files and folders from the current folder to destination folder successfully. However it shows the error **"the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"**

My script:

```
mkdir filestobehere
$dest = '.\filestobehere'
Move-Item .\* $dest -Exclude $dest -Force
I am stumped.
```

I tried to try catch, but it is not being caught and I still get the error.

```
mkdir filestobehere
Get-ChildItem -Path "./" |
ForEach-Object {
  $dest = '.\filestobehere'
  Try {
    Move-Item .\* $dest -Exclude $dest -Force
  }
  Catch {
    Write-Hose "File is in use"
  }
}
```

Comment: [Move-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/move-item?view=powershell-7.3#-exclude): _The Exclude parameter is effective only when the command includes the contents of an item, such as `C:\Windows\*`, where the wildcard character specifies the contents of the C:\Windows directory._

Comment: @Theo i thought I can use the Exclude since my source path is .\* aka the contents of my current directory

Comment: No, you set Exclude to the literal string `'.\filestobehere'`

Comment: @Theo I appended ErrorAction Stop to the Move-Item and it now prints "File is in use". However if I write 'Write-Host "File $($_.FullName) is in use", I wonder why it does not write the file name?

Comment: That's because in your Catch block you do not show the **real** error, just your own text `"File is in use"`.. Change that to `$_.Exception.Message`. Did you read my first comment about the `-Exclude` switch? It won't work on file paths, just on the file Names..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the primary problem with your attempt is that **you're using a *path* as your `-Exclude` argument, which isn't supported**.<sup>[1]</sup>

As a result, the exclusion attempt is ineffective, and [`Move-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/move-item) attempts to move the `filestobehere` subdirectory to itself, which predictably fails (I do see a different error, however).

While using only a file *name*  with `-Exclude` fixes the problem with your command in [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), a bug in *Windows PowerShell* prevents targeting the excluded name as the (possibly positionally implied) `-Destination` argument.

A solution that works in both PowerShell editions:

```bash
$dest = 'filestobehere' # OMIT the ".\"
Get-Item .\* -Exclude $dest | Move-Item -Force -Destination $dest
```

---

<sup>[1] as of PowerShell 7.3.0; however, there are two relevant feature requests: [GitHub issue #15159](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15159) and [GitHub issue #4126](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4126).</sup>